# How to beign call useEffect hook two time

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to use useEffect two times:

**-when first-time component loaded**

**-when a specific value changed**

how to implement both scenarios?
best regards

Comment: Use the specific value as the dependency in the dependency array. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#timing-of-effects What you describe wanting are the exact times the `useEffect` hook w/dependency callback is called. What have you tried already? What isn't working as expected? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What did you try? What you're describing is a fundamental use-case of the `useEffect` hook. Please read the docs on the subject, try it out, and *then* post a question if you are stuck with a specific problem.

Comment: How can run two scenarios together? (when a component first load and when a specific value changes)

Comment: Have you read the docs linked yet? They directly answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Simply by putting the `value` into the `useEffect` call's dependencies.

Since moving from "no value" (i.e. before mount) to having a value (at initial mount) is a change of value, it does the trick.

Comment: How can run two scenarios together? (when a component first load and when a specific value changes)

Answer (score 0):

enter a specific value in dep

```
useEffect(()=>{

},[anyValueState])
```

Comment: and then when a component is first rendered, how can run two scenarios together?